# Any Realm browser for Windows user

Tags: realm

Is there any Realm db browser for Windows user?

Currently they only have a browser for MAC user.

Where can I get an open source browser?

Answer (score 0):

[Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) plugin for browsing Realm would soon be available. You'd be able to browse a Realm database on many platforms including Windows.